# I've been trying to solve this particular geometry problem for 3 to 4 days but have finally given up

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I know the solution that is 30 degrees here but I need to know the method so that I can extend it to a general solution. A method with linear equations will be very helpful.

ABCD is a square. Isosceles triangle ABE has base angles measuring 15 degrees. We need to find the angle ECB namely alpha.

Here is the image of the diagram.We need to find the unknown angle alpha.[image]

Comment: Can you use trig?

Comment: Yes,but I would really appreciate the use of linear equations.

Comment: This is, unsurprisingly, known as the $15^{\circ}$ problem, see, e.g. [this](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMT668/EMAT6680.F99/Estes/15degrees/15degreeproblem.html)

Comment: @lulu Sorry but the link is not working.

Comment: The link works fine for me

Comment: This question looks familiar. Did you already ask it recently?

Comment: No.But yeah,I found it on Instagram and then lost it by swiping up.

Comment: Most geometry problems are solved on the 5th day.

Comment: Wait up,guys I think I got it now. Thank y'all so much. But it's still trig that came to my help.Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Construct the mid line PQ as shown.

[image]

Let the square ABCD be $2 \times 2$; and E’ be a point on PQ such that triangle BE’C is equilateral.

Then, $\triangle PE’C$ is an $1 – 2 – \sqrt 3$ triangle with ($\gamma = 60^0$ and $\beta = 30^0$ PC = 1 and CE’ = 2) as shown.

Therefore, $\triangle CE’D$ is isosceles with $\angle CDE’ = 75^0$

Hence, $\angle ADE’ = 15^0$ indicating E’ is actually E.

Comment: This is a good argument, but I don't think you need the second paragraph at all since the lengths $CE'$ and $CD$ give you that it's isoceles. Also, your diagram has lots of extraneous symbols.

Comment: @Suzu Hirose Had you worked with Geogebra or Desmos, you should know that this "lot of extraneous symbols" are due to the default mode which displays the names for everything !

Comment: @SuzuHirose In fact, I have some of the symbols hidden already.

Answer (score 0):

Direct proof using Pythagoras Theorem:

1. Connect the midpoint ($M$) of the square base to the point $E$.
2. Let the distance between point $E$ and the triangle base have length $x$.
3. Now, it should be clear that
   $$\tan(15) = \frac{x}{1/2} = 2x.$$
   and
   $$\tan(\alpha) = \frac{1/2}{1-x} = \frac{1}{2-2x} = \frac{1}{2-\tan(15)}.$$

Now, to compute $\tan(15)$, we utilize the identity for tangent.
$$\tan(\alpha) = 2\frac{\tan(\alpha/2)}{1-\tan(\alpha/2)^2}$$
so that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} = \tan(30) = 2\frac{\tan(15)}{1-\tan(15)^2}.$$
Letting $x = \tan(15)$ and rearranging, we find the quadratic
$$-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}x^2-x+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} = 0.$$
Solving gives,
$$x = 2-\sqrt{3}.$$
So,
$$\tan(\alpha) = \frac{1}{2-(2-\sqrt{3})} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}.$$
Therefore, $\alpha = 30$.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that $\tan\alpha\neq 30$, I think you have missed a step here.

Comment: @Suzu Hirose The expression "missed step" is exaggerated ;  only a typo : $\alpha = 30°$.

Comment: To make last step, you need to know tan(15°).